# How to pass Powershell argument with -silent

Tags: powershell

Here is my ps script:-

```
param (
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='runParam', Position=1, Mandatory=$false)]
    [String]$runParam
)

Write-Host $runParam
```

I would like to pass an argument with `-silent`. It doesn't allow me to pass any argument with `-`

Is there any way to pass an argument with `-` ?

I can execute and pass any argument without `-`. It works fine. But I have to pass it as `-silent`

I get error as:-

> run.ps1 : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name
>   'silent'. At line:1 char:11
>   + .\run.ps1 -silent
>   +           ~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [run.ps1], ParameterBindingException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,run.ps1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read [`Get-Help 'about_parameters'`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parameters?view=powershell-5.1)

> Most Windows PowerShell commands, such as cmdlets, functions, and
>   scripts,  rely on parameters to allow users to select options or
>   provide input. The  parameters follow the command name and have the
>   following form:
>
> ```
>     -<parameter_name> <parameter_value>
> ```
>
> The name of the parameter is preceded by a hyphen (`-`), which signals
>   to   Windows PowerShell that the word following the hyphen is a
>   parameter name.

Choose any of the following methods to pass a leading hyphen as a string

```
PS D:\PShell> .\run.ps1 -runParam -silent ### declared parameter type is string
-silent
PS D:\PShell> .\run.ps1 `-silent          ### escape: a backtick character
-silent
PS D:\PShell> .\run.ps1 '-silent'         ### escape: single quotes
-silent
PS D:\PShell> .\run.ps1 "-silent"         ### escape: double quotes
-silent
```